# Parse regex query

Tags: c#, regex

I have a formula in french that I want to convert to english
See below:

```
Initial: =SI(renamed="SI";SI(f1<f4;"SI(";"nok");"1;2")
Must be converted to: =IF(renamed="SI",IF(f1<f4,"SI(";"nok"),"1;2")
```

2 issues:

- ; must be converted to , ( but not inside strings " xxx ; xxx "
- SI must be renamed to IF ( but not inside strings " xxx SI xxx "

I have this regex as a good beginning :`([^=;]*)\(` at 
https://regex101.com/r/OPyLh1/3

Actually, this is just a sample with the work IF /SI but I have around one hundred words to convert between french and english

What would be the best approach to achieve this ( a mix of regex + code ?)
we are doing development in C#

Comment: It´s hard to help you with just that single input. What are the fix parts and what may change?

Comment: Try to write some unit tests out of some examples. Then try to compose a regexp / or code + regexp to pass the tests.

Comment: If, as I suspect, you're dealing with localized Excel formulas, you may also want to take a look at the [Excel function translator](https://support.office.com/article/excel-functions-translator-f262d0c0-991c-485b-89b6-32cc8d326889), which is specifically designed for this task. Doing this translation with regexes alone is anything but comfortable on fully generic input.

Comment: exactly. We have to implement a programmatic translation between french and english formulas in SharePoint. When we create a field with a formula, the sharepoint API wants it in english and we have only the french versiions.

Answer (score 1):

Design of an expression for this problem is rather complicated, might depends on inputs that we might have, and understanding the technicalities, which I'm simply not sure about the last. Then, we can define a set of rules to find what we wish to replace. For example, this expression would capture those `;` and `SI` included in the question using logical ORs:

```
(SI)|["](;)[A-Z]|[0-9](;)["]|[)](;)["]
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9s2wjf/1/)

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(SI)|[""](;)[A-Z]|[0-9](;)[""]|[)](;)[""]";
        string input = @"=SI(renamed=""SI"";SI(f1<f4;""SI("";""nok"");""1;2"")";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired or you wish to modify it, please visit [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/9s2wjf/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: actually this does not entirely work.  It found the "SI" contained in the string : =SI(renamed="SI" etc... It should have excluded "SI" and "SI(";"nok")